# I want to find list of files (under some directory, recursively) in which the string <some_string> is written

Tags: linux

what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep -R <some_string> <directory>`

Comment: Add the --files-with-matches option if you only want a list of files and not the text printed from the grep call.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
find . -name "*.cpp" | xargs grep some_string
```

if you want to restrict the search to particular file patterns or types. With `find`, you can also specify the maximum depth to search.